# Deleting blogger post leads to crawl error

Tags: google-search-console, blog, blogger

i deleted the blog post from blogger, now i have got crawler error in webmaster account i.e page is pointing to 404 . Kindly help me how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really anything you can do other than wait for the search engines to drop that page from their index. They have a page of yours that used to exist, you deleted it, but they continue to check to make sure it wasn't a temporary error. If they dropped a page as soon as one 404 error was returned it would cause a lot of trouble for some people. Say they crawled your site at the same time the server was temporarily down, your whole site would be dropped from the search engine, which would be very bad.

So, don't do anything, the crawl error you're seeing shouldn't cause you any problems, and eventually they'll stop checking for that page and the error will go away.

Comment: Thanks, but i was in .blogspot domain & i moved to .com, now all the links of post are updated in google but new post links taking lots of time to appear, but before i.e in blogspot domain it use to appear as soon as i hit publish,, wats cause for it?

Comment: if the content remains but with a different URL you should do a 301 redirect from the old to the new urls